# Can we use Eventarc to trigger a google workflow only if certain set of google workflows get executed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, workflow, eventtrigger, event-arc

I am having use case where one workflow needs to be executed if certain n no. of workflows gets completed. Can we achieve this using eventarc trigger feature of Google Cloud ?

Comment: No, you can't do that. I submitted a feature request to the team to have this kind of event sync hub that wait several events before triggering a new one

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.